# google maps - open marker infowindow given the coordinates

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using google maps api v3.

Using javascript, how can i open the infowindow of a marker given it's coordinates?

Comment: can you please share some code? do u have the markers saved?

Comment: yes the markers are saved and show on the map. i have a list of links outside the map, which when i currently click i am centering the map to them coordinates but i also want it to load the info window of the marker at them coordinates

Comment: pls share the code on jsbin or jsfiddle so we can fix it in a second. ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/3CvaD/) that shows you how to do an "outside" of the map JavaScript interaction w/ the Markers.  Yes, you do need to save the markers and it's appropriate InfoWindow within an array so you can access it.  I created two random markers and use the coordinates from the array ships.

Here are the HTML and with two generic links where clicking link one would center to maker 1 and popup its infowindow and for marker 2 vise versa:

```
    <div id='map_canvas'></div>
    <a href='#' onClick="gotoPoint(1);">Click for marker 1</a><br/>
    <a href='#' onClick="gotoPoint(2);">Click for marker 2</a>
```

Within createMarker i store the created maker along with its associate InfoWindow and push it onto the global scope's marker array.  On hover the marker, it'll open its associate infowindow:

```
function createMarker(lat, lon, html) {
    var newmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
        map: map,
        title: html
    });

    newmarker['infowindow'] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: html
        });

    google.maps.event.addListener(newmarker, 'mouseover', function() {
        this['infowindow'].open(map, this);
    });

    marker.push(newmarker);
}
```

Here in gotoPoint i simply ass in the marker number as a parameter.  I basically set the center of the map to that of marker by using `new google.maps.LatLng` and use the marker's lat and lng by calling `marker[myPoint-1].position.lat();` and `marker[myPoint-1].position.lng();`, and open its associate InfoWindow with `marker[myPoint-1]['infowindow'].open(map, marker[myPoint-1]);`:

```
function gotoPoint(myPoint){
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(marker[myPoint-1].position.lat(), marker[myPoint-1].position.lng()));
    marker[myPoint-1]['infowindow'].open(map, marker[myPoint-1]);
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions about this example.

Comment: eg http://nerddinner.com/ i know its not google maps but when you hover the links it loads a window.

Comment: @raklos yes, you can do that give me a few mins to put up a little code

Comment: Seems a great answer, how would you use this code, if you only wanted one info window open at a time?