# different content in multiple infowindows for google maps api v3

Tags: google-maps

I am working on a project using google maps api v3 and am trying to make it so when a marker is clicked on a infowindow appears. I have accomplished this but now what i want is different content to be displayed when different markers are clicked on which i can't seem to figure out. any help is appreciated. thanks!

```
    function initialize() {

var locations = [
      ['Phi Delta Theta', 39.511747,-84.735117],
      ['Pi Kappa Alpha', 39.511776, -84.735684],
      ['Sigma Nu', 39.513921, -84.735159],
      ['Sigma Alpha Epsilon', 39.514332, -84.734956],
      ['Beta Theta Pi', 39.5107519, -84.738549]
    ];

var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.511747,-84.735117);
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 15,
  center: myLatlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

var contentString = '<div id="content">'+

    '</div>';

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
});

var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
      }


google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
});



      }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the answer that does what you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868903/marker-content-infowindow-google-maps), however it allows to open multiple infoWindow at once.
The point of it is to define multiple instances of windowinfo.
Instead of:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
});
....
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

}
```

do smth like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });
}
```

That way you will define multiple markers, each with different content.