# Is there a way to associate a marker to text?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

In the old Google Maps, one used to be able to search something, hover over one of the results, and the corresponding marker on the map would be enlarged.

This isn't in the new Google Maps, because only one result is shown, but is this still possible? I want to be able to mouseover a particular div that contains an address and for a marker on a Google Maps that is located at that address to be enlarged.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to tie the event listeners of the div and the appropriate marker together. Its not a default function of the api but it is relatively simple.

See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5068556/1856970) for a related solution. Effectively you need to trigger the mouse over event of the appropriate marker from the mouse over of your div. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure if this what I'm looking for (or maybe it is). I was looking for something along the lines of:

https://www.google.com/maps?t=m&ll=42.3644454,-71.103187&z=15&output=classic&dg=opt

If you search for something and when you hover over any of the results, the marker expands. Is this possible?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no simple way to achieve this, you will have to tie the event listeners.